# What datatype in SQLite to use in this case?

Tags: sqlite

Given the following list of numbers, I wanted to calculate the same formula in different environments and hoped that they would be close, here is what I came up with:

```
**Data**
0.884805739
0.579941876
0.707207324
0.076841269

**Excel**
=SUM(C2:C5)/4 - MAX(C2:C5)/3
Result:
0.267263806

**SQLite**
SELECT (SUM(A)/4) - (MAX(A)/3) FROM XL
Result:
0.267263333

**C#**
decimal d = ((0.884805739M+0.579941876M +0.707207324M+0.076841269M)/4M) - (0.884805739M/3M);
Result
0.2672638056666666666666666667
```

The SQLite result is the one that looks significantly different from the other two values. The column in Sqlite is defined as Decimal(15,9) and I also tested it with NUMBER and other precisions. I understand that Decimal and Number are treated as FLOAT in SQLite and that FLOAT is not precise and that not all decimal values can be accurately represented in binary format which is probably the reason for this value difference.

My question now is:
What datatype to use in SQLite to produce a result close to Excel and/or C#? Thx.

Comment: In SQlite I get the same value as in C# (also same value in Python with float). SQlite REAL is a 64-bit float (aka `double`) the same as in Python. I suspect the Decimal type is _not_ causing the difference that you see.

Comment: I am not sure what else would cause it?

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3e5b2/1). It's possible that the SQLite values got rounded when inserting or when being output. What software did you use for that?

Comment: @CL, thanks for your help, it was the client I am using. I checked your link and another client interface that produced the correct result. If you care to post your comment as an answer I will mark it as such. Thx again.

Comment: If the problem is your software, you have to write the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting six decimal digits of precision from SQLite, which suggests you're using a 32-bit version. A 64-bit version should return a value closer to 0.267263805666667 (15 decimal digits of precision).

You can't fix this in SQLite by using a different data type (type affinity). You need to use a 64-bit version instead.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @CL, the client software I used was not performing the calculations accurately! I switched to a different client on Windows 32-bit machine and got the answer to be:
**0.2672638056**96402 which is also close to the value **2672638056**66667 calculated by SQL Fiddle suggested by @CL. However, I am not sure why are these 2 answers different?